# Overlay numbers from 0000 to 9999 on a picture

Tags: image, autoit

I have a picture with some white/blank space. My goal is to automatically generate a number from 0000 to 9999 and put it on top of the picture, then export/save it as a png.

the result should be

mypicture_0000.png

mypicture_0001.png

...

mypicture_9999.png

Has anyone tried something similar?
I am thinking about trying autoit, but will that work? If so which software should I use with autoit?

Thank You.

Comment: See you accepted a Python answer. But here is the way to go in AutoIt: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/49065-imagemagick-object/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should not be much of a problem if you have Python and the [Python Imaging Library (PIL)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) installed:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

BACKGROUND = '/path/to/background.png'
OUTPUT = '/path/to/mypicture_{0:04d}.png'
START = 0
STOP = 9999

# Create a font object from a True-Type font file and specify the font size.
fontobj = ImageFont.truetype('/path/to/font/arial.ttf', 24)

for i in range(START, STOP + 1):
    img = Image.open(BACKGROUND)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    # Write a text over the background image.
    # Parameters: location(x, y), text, textcolor(R, G, B), fontobject
    draw.text((0, 0), '{0:04d}'.format(i), (255, 0, 0), font=fontobj)
    img.save(OUTPUT.format(i))

print 'Script done!'
```

Please consult the PIL manual for other ways of creating font objects for other font formats

Answer (score 1):

autoit may work.  i'd use python PIL.  i can specify font, convert it to a layer and overlay on top of preexisting image.

**EDIT** 
actually imagemagick can be easier than PIL  http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/